# Increase AChartEngine TimeSeries performance?

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a considerable large number of points ( about 20 000 ) which i wish to visualize as a TimeSeries values. Anyway the performance drop down to a few frames per second, and the loading is very slow.
I don't need labels on each point on the series, neither the points.

- How to increase performance of AChartEngine's TimeSeries ?
- Will removing the labels on each point, and the point itself increase performance, and how to do it, if it does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start my answer with a question: how do you visualize 20000 points on a small device screen? I find it difficult even on a high resolution desktop display.

The AChartEngine model design was greatly improved a few years ago to support such a number of points, so a few frames per second sounds decently for this amount of values. I suggest you dynamically add and remove data from your model such as you don't store that many. The performance will start increasing.

Comment: Hello Dan. My target is 5.5" and higher screen size GSM's and tablets. Currently I am doing it on 5.7" quad core Full HD GSM.
Your idea is good, but I trying to show the peoples the whole thing :|
It's just important for the users to see the whole thing without need of scrolling, while the points and the labels is not so important, and i am very thinking that they might be at least a bit of performance killers.

Comment: There are plenty decimation algorithms allowing you to transform 20k points to something like 2k and nobody will notice the difference in the way it looks.

Comment: The data shall remain untouched. It is a very important requirement. That's why we switched back on web ( the same but web based application ) from HTML5 to Flex - since HTML5 produced 2 GB footprint on 20 000 points, while Flex remain in 50 MB... but this is another story..

Comment: I am not asking you to change your data. You can change only the stuff you add to the AChartEngine model. Anyway, good luck!